# How to execute Nutch with Selenium plugin?

Tags: selenium, nutch

I am trying to run [nutch with selenium plugin](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/trunk/src/plugin/protocol-selenium) but could not get it how execute Nutch or crawl website as I am a beginner.

Done with xml changes as per the setup required:

```
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-selenium|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|scoring-opic</value>
    <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
    include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
    In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
    default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
    and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable 
    protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the 
    underlying commons-httpclient library.
    </description>
```

I want to execute the nutch with selenium to test web page having javascript?

Comment: Detailed instructions are given in the [README of the plugin protocol-selenium](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium). It's strongly recommended to use a recent version of Apache Nutch 1.x if not the development version.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SebastianNagel but there is no specific command/ways to execute selenium with nutch on the link shared.  it would be really a great help if you  can  elaborate little more on this!  Thanks in advance

Comment: NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/crawl /opt/apache-nutch-2.2.1/urls/ webpage $NUTCH_SOLR_SERVER $NUTCH_CRAWL_DEPTH ---@SebastianNagel can you please eloborate on this command what do we understand about web page

Comment: Executing nutch selenium plugin command make it to execute

Comment: bin/nutch plugin protocol-selenium org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.Http passUrUrl

Comment: Thank you very much  @SebastianNagel for your kind input on the same

Comment: Using nutch protocol-selenium plugin make it execute and solved my problem thank you